# Stored procedure not returning the expected value

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Stored procedure is not returning the value that I am expecting. I did not know what is the problem with the procedure.

Here is the procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure PRC_CUSTOMER_WITH_LOGIN
    (p_name_out out varchar2,
     p_count out int,
     p_all_records out SYS_REFCURSOR,
     p_mode in varchar2,
     p_id in varchar2,
     p_name_in in varchar2,
     p_contact_no in varchar2,
     p_email in varchar2,
     p_address in varchar2)
IS
BEGIN
IF p_mode='q' 
THEN
    select NAME into p_name_out from customer where id='1';
ELSIF p_mode='i' 
THEN
    INSERT into customer(id,name,contactNo,email,address)
    Values(p_id, p_name_in, p_contact_no , p_email , p_address);
ELSIF p_mode='u' 
THEN
    UPDATE customer set name=p_name_in, contactNo=p_contact_no, email=p_email, address=p_address
     where id=p_id;
ELSIF p_mode='d' 
THEN
    DELETE from customer where id=p_id;
ELSIF p_mode='a'
THEN
    OPEN p_all_records FOR
        select * from customer;
ELSIF p_mode='l'
THEN
    SELECT COUNT(*) into p_count from customer WHERE name=p_name_in AND id=p_id;
END IF;
END;
/
```

This is the procedure all other conditions are working fine but the last condition is not working correctly this condition return 0 all the time whether I enter the correct id and name or wrong.

Here I am calling this procedure

```
cs = (OracleCallableStatement) con.prepareCall("{call TESTDB.PRC_CUSTOMER_WITH_LOGIN(?,?,?,?,?,?,null,null,null)}");
            cs.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
            cs.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.INTEGER);
            cs.registerOutParameter(3, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
            cs.setString(4, "l");
            cs.setString(5, password);
            cs.setString(6, name);

            cs.executeQuery();
            chk=cs.getInt(2);
            System.out.println(chk);
```

Can someone tell me what the mistake is that I'm making here? I shall be thankful .... :)

Comment: you can debug your code, if you dont have any tool like toad, sql developer etc then you can print the values and query on your screen. Fire the same query generated in your procedure to your db. You will get your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use UPPER both side so if any case sensitive names are there then it will nullify it.

SELECT COUNT(*) into p_count from customer WHERE upper(name)=upper(p_name_in) AND id=p_id;

Comment: i am giving correct name as present in the database.

Comment: Have u checked for leading and trailing spaces for the name?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are wrong when you set `id` with the `password` value?

```
1-> p_name_out out varchar2,
2-> p_count out int,
3-> p_all_records out SYS_REFCURSOR,
4-> p_mode in varchar2,
5-> p_id in varchar2,      --- 5 is id, not password ??!?
6-> p_name_in in varchar2,
p_contact_no in varchar2,
p_email in varchar2,
p_address in varchar2

cs = (OracleCallableStatement) con.prepareCall(
"{call TESTDB.PRC_CUSTOMER_WITH_LOGIN(?,?,?,?,?,?,null,null,null)}");
        cs.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
        cs.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.INTEGER);
        cs.registerOutParameter(3, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
        cs.setString(4, "l");
        cs.setString(5, password);
        cs.setString(6, name);
```

Another possibility is  your *id/password* is stored as encrypted thing?